# Output datetime value to StaticTextField in SmartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have a field in my dataset defined as:

```
DataSourceDateTimeField dateField = new DataSourceDateTimeField("date");
```

and a `StaticTextItem` in `DynamicForm` defined as

```
StaticTextItem dateItem = new StaticTextItem("date", "Date");
```

I played a lot with different combinations of `setDateFormatter`, but datetime values are still rendered as something like `2011-08-23T20:00:00` (datasource receives it in json as a `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` field).

Is there some easy way to output datetime values to `StaticTextItem`? I assume using `DynamicForm.fetchData()`.

---

UPD1. Data example.

Table row in PgSQL:

```
1 | "2011-09-29 12:10:05.010276+04" | "Europe"
```

Data sent by REST service:

```
{
  "location":"Europe",
  "id":1,
  "date":"2011-09-29T08:10:05.010+0000"
}
```

Data fetched by SGWT from REST service (I dumped it with `JSON.encode(XMLTools.selectObjects(data, "/").getJavaScriptObject())` in my implementation of `transformResponse()`) :

```
{
  "location":"Europe", 
  "id":1, 
  "date":"2011-09-29T08:10:05"
}
```

Value as rendered in StaticTextField:

```
2011-09-29T08:10:05
```

So datetime values returned by server seem to conform the [standard](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp) and also I have no warnings in Developer Console.

---

UPD2. May be I'm doing something wrong in my `transformResponse()` ?

```
protected void transformResponse(DSResponse response, DSRequest request, Object data) {

  String json = JSON.encode(XMLTools.selectObjects(data, "/").getJavaScriptObject());

  SC.logWarn("Response received");
  SC.logWarn(json);

  Record[] records = jsonToRecords(json);
  //safe HTML text values
  for (Record rec: records) {
    for (DataSourceField field: getFields()) {
      if (field.getType() == FieldType.TEXT) {
        String textVal = rec.getAttribute(field.getName());
        if (textVal != null) {
          textVal = SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape(textVal);  
        }    
        rec.setAttribute(field.getName(), textVal);
      }
    }
  }

  response.setData(records);    
  response.setStartRow(0);
  response.setEndRow(records.length);
  response.setTotalRows(records.length);
}

/**
* Converts JS-array into SmartGWT records
*/
public static native ListGridRecord[] jsonToRecords(String jsonString) /*-{
  var json = eval(jsonString);
  return @com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid::convertToListGridRecordArray(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(json);
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that your date value is still a String, not an instance of Date.  It should have been parsed into a Date when the JSON response was received - if it was not, there will be a warning in the SmartGWT Developer Console tell you so.

The format expected for date values in documented under DataSource.dataFormat - XML Schema date/datetime format is expected by default, and you can provide a FieldValueParser if you are unable to make your server produce this format.

Comment: I've checked it. All datetime values returned by server seem to conform the standard and also I have no warnings in Developer Console.

Comment: Yes, the problem is your transformResponse().  SmartGWT has parsed the String values into dates, but you are completely overwriting this with a new set of Records you created yourself in jsonToRecord().  You should use the original records and replace values selectively if you need to.

Comment: Thank you very much, Charles. I've just added `super.transformResponse(response, request, data);` at the beginning and removed `response.setData(records);` and it seems to work nice.